# Animation of letters filling After Effect

Tags: adobe, stroke, after-effects

Is it possible to animate text/object with 'end' in after effects just like you do with strokes? How can I achieve this? See the video and you'll understand what I wan't to achieve.
[YouTube - Guy showing the 'end' on a stroke](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=d0xNnLQtqLI#t=180)

*Cheers,
Tommie*

Answer (score 0):

I think I see what you are asking. You want the shapes of a text layer (the actual lines of each character) to actually build on, right? Can't be done like that. Even if you use text and convert to shapes, you are looking at a world of pain because of the way letters are built by most fonts (for one thing, the shapes are actually filled, not stroked -- strokes are outlines).
The only way I would do this is by using the Element 3D plugin in After Effects and Cheetah3D (or whatever 3D tool you want to use). In Cheetah, I'd create the text shapes as extruded 3D text. Then I'd use the "Build" modifier ("Linear" setting) to progressively build the text. Then I'd export that out as an OBJ sequence (script for this is available on cheetah forum site -- I wrote it) and bring that sequence into Element3D and work with it that way. That will work. And as far as I know, that's the only way with a decent amount of control. Wedding video? Just curious. :-)